# programmatically change the background color in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, colors, plugins, background

I have a question related to eclipse plugin development. Is there any means
by which I can programmatically change the background color in eclipse.
     I am able to change the text foreground color by calling
setTextColor(color, offset, length, controlRedraw) in ITextViewer
but I don't find any function by which I can change the background
color of the text.
       If anyone has been through this kindly share your thoughts.

Thanks
arav

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this can be done easily, short of extending your own version of a Text Editor,  here you provide a `Configuration` Class which inturn accepts a `PresentationReconciler` Class which is like a `Rule` Class that tells you if you need to put a Foreground or a Background Color

See [this document](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/platform-text-home/eclipseCon/2006/texteditorrecipes.pdf?revision=1.2)

**PresentationReconciler**

- `IPresentationDamager`: define dirty region given a text change
- `IPresentationRepairer`: recreate presentation for dirty region
- `DefaultDamagerRepairer` does both, based on a token scanner
- `ITokenScanner`: parse text into a token stream
- `RuleBasedScanner` uses simple rules

Extract from the presentation

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20140715222227/http://img266.i_mageshack.us/img266/5465/setrules2.png]

<sub>From Text Editor Recipes, Season’s recipes for your text editor

**Tom Eicher**, IBM Eclipse Team</sub>

Here, the null background color means, takes the default system background for that widget. (so here: white).
But you could specify whatever color you want, based on the partitioning of your document and on the rules that would apply.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while ago, but in case anyone is looking for another solution, I thought I would post the following:

Since you are able to use the setTextColor method, then you should be able to use the changeTextPresentation method as well.

In the case of my plug-in, I have a TextListener that calls the TextChanged method I overwrote.  I did the following to add background color using the changeTextPresentation method.  In doing so, I was able to get a Green background with Black foreground.  Not that I would want this, of course, but just for testing purposes.

```
public void TextChanged(TextEvent event){
...
TextPresentation presentation = new TextPresentation();
TextAttribute attr = new TextAttribute(new ColorManager().getColor(MyConstants.BLACK),
      new ColorManager().getColor(MyConstants.GREEN), style);
presentation.addStyleRange(new StyleRange(startOffset, tokLength, attr.getForeground(),
      attr.getBackground());
sourceViewer.changeTextPresentation(presentation, true); //sourceViewer is a global variable passed to my TextListener class constructor.
}
```